# How do I persist a Map<String, Map<String, String>> with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> someMap = new HashMap<>();
```

How can one persist this with JPA 2.1?

Comment: create an intermediate object containing a Map<String, String> then this becomes the value of the original map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize it and store it as blob in one column:

```
@Lob
HashMap<String, Map<String, String>> someMap = new HashMap<>(); 
//!!!!it needs to be declared as HashMap not Map as Serializable is required for this field
```

But it works only if you dont want to run queries against content of the map, as in the DB it is stored of course as a sequence of bytes that DB does not understand.

You cannot have @ElementCollection of @ElementCollection in JPA and that is what you would need to have 2 level of maps.